# ¿Cómo puedo corregir este error : ValueError: Location based indexing can only have ...?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Agradeceré ayuda para fijar este error

```
# Consulta stackoverflow
start = "2016-01-04"
end = "2019-01-04"

#Imortar cotizaciones
start = "2016-01-04"
end = "2019-01-04"
iberdrola = pdr.DataReader("IBE.MC", "yahoo", start, end)
df = iberdrola[["Close"]].copy(deep=True)

# Añadimos columnas nuevas introduciendo el valor 0
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(
       [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]], 
       index=df_dca.index, 
       columns=['inversion', 'inver_acum', 'pendiente_invertir','acc_compradas', 'acc_acum', 'acc_compradas', 'valor_actual']
))

nºfilas = df.shape[0]
paso = round(nºfilas/12,0)
filas = np.absolute(np.arange(0, nºfilas, paso))

# Cálculos
for i in range (0, len(indices)):
    # Acciones compradas
    df.iloc[filas[i], 2] = porcion / df.iloc[filas[i], 0]
    # Inversión periódica
    df.iloc[filas[i], 1] = porcion

df
```

Me devuelve:

```
..........................
24     df.iloc[indices[i], 2] = porcion / df_dca_dca.iloc[indices[i], 0]
...................................
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types
```

Comment: `iloc[]` requiere que lo que pongas dentro de los corchetes sean enteros. Le estás pasando `indices[i]` que, de forma general, no es un entero sino el nombre de un índice. Yo creo que si pasas simplemente `.iloc[i, 2]` consigues lo que pretendías. O si no, tal vez debas usar `.loc[indices[i], 2]`, si `2` era el nombre de una columna en vez de su índice entero.

Comment: Pero, "indices", es una lista de números enteros, luego "indices[i] es un número entero.

Comment: Pues posiblemente no lo sea, ya que el error te está diciendo precisamente que no es un entero. Es bastante probable que tu lista de índices contenga en realidad `float`, por la forma en que la construyes, ya que `paso` aunque lo redondeas mediante `round()` es en realidad un `float`. Quizás si lo conviertes a `int()` funcione.

Comment: Creo que el nombre "indice", de la lista, puede inducirnos a error de compresión del script. Lo he cambiado por "filas", ya que es una lista con el número de orden de las filas en las que quiero modificar ciertos datos. ¿Te aclara esto algo más?

Comment: Con el nombre `filas` está más claro, pero de todas formas ya tenía claro de qué se trataba y reitero lo antes dicho. El problema viene de que `paso` es de tipo `float` debido al `round(x, 0)`. Por tanto el `arange()` te genera una lista de floats. Y por tanto `filas[i]` es un float que no puede usarse como índice

Answer (score -1):

Abufalia, Lo que me has indicado resuelve el problema.

> De todas formas respondiendo a lo que dices, `np.arange(0, 10, 2.0).astype(int)` debería funcionar. También funcionaría si paso fuese entero, de modo que podías haber hecho `np.arange(0, nºfilas, int(paso))`